# Влияет ли блок скрытый через display:none; на скорость загрузки страницы

Tags: css, html5

Возможно очень нубский вопрос, но я озадачился.
Есть 2 блока:

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="mobile">
  <ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Если скрыть в десктопе блок mobile, через @media-запрос - увеличит ли это скорость загрузки страницы или нет? И соответственно если в мобильной версии скрыть скрыть таким же образом desktop, будет ли увеличена скорость загрузки страницы или нет?

По сути, вне зависимости от того display: none; у блока стоит или нет - браузер всё равно строит эту верстку и рисует стили, только не выводит их.... или я что, не так понимаю..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ВЛИЯЕТ**, но использование display: none ---- не приветствуется для оптимизации SEO.
Нужно тестировать код, для выявления сбора информации загрузки скриптов и стилей документа.

Comment: @Rostovpapa А как тогда, интересно, при адаптации, скрывать ненужные блоки в мобильной версии? visibility: none; - так они кликабельны, и все равно остаются на странице и грузятся в DOM. Допустим кликабельность можно убрать, но результат тот же получается, что и при display: none;